# How to align an epigraph item

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align, epigraphs, quotation

I have the following epigraph object

```
\usepackage{epigraph}


\epigraph{ "Some quote."}{\textit{From me.}
```

Initially, the epigraph object sticks to the right margin. Is it possible to center the object, or perhaps even align it to right margin? I have attempted the likes of

```
\begin{center}
\epigraph{ "Some quote."}{\textit{From me.}
\end{center}
```

But it does note work. Furthermore, rather than having a horizontal line separating `"Some quote."` from `From me.` , I want to only have a dash in the sense `-From me` below the quote `"Some quote."`. I have already attempted to consult some summaries of the `epigraph` package, however, I could not find anything. Any ideas?

Comment: This may not be the actual solution to your problem, but still something you should absolutely fix: there is a closing curly brace missing in your code. It should be `\epigraph{"Some quote."}{\textit{From me.}}`.

Comment: For quotation marks I would suggest the package `csquotes`, then you can write `\enquote{Some quote.}` to get good looking quotation marks. (It may be possible to modify `\epigraph` to print the quotation marks and italics automatically. That would save you some typing.)

Comment: What do you mean by "align it to right margin"? Can you add a picture of what you mean?

Comment: You may want to try `\renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{center}` or `\renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{flushleft}`. `\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}` can help you get rid of the line. There are many more options. Have a look at the `eprigraph` documentation: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/epigraph/epigraph.pdf. An alternative package with a different interface and option handling is https://ctan.org/pkg/epigraph-keys

Comment: It works, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The position of the epigraph can be controlled by redefining `\epigraphflush`. The default value is `flushright` and prints the epigraph at the right side of the page. With

```
\renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{center}
```

you get it at the centre or the page and with

```
\renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{flushleft}
```

at the left side.

The line can be controlled by setting the length `\epigraphrule`. If that length is `0pt` the rule vanishes.

```
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
```

For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{center}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\epigraph{\enquote{Some quote.}}{\textit{--- From me.}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Some quote ---From me]

The package offers more settings to modify the appearance of the epigraph. You can modify `\textflush` and `\sourceflush` for the alignment of text and source (both are `flushright` by default; they work like `\epigraphflush` and can take the values `\flusright`, `\center` and `\flushleft`).

---

An alternative to the `epigraph` package could be the [`epigraph-keys` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/epigraph-keys). It offers a slightly more compact key-value interface for customisation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{epigraph-keys}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\epigraph[author={From me.}, quote style={}]{\enquote{Some quote.}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Some quote --- From me]

---

Unfortunately, neither package offers a simple way to automatically add the quotes without having to add them explicitly with `\enquote`, but I guess one normally does not enclose the complete epigraph with quotation marks since it is clear that it is a quotation.

I used `csquotes`' `\enquote` commands instead of `"`, because `csquotes` gives you typographically nice quotation marks (and you don't have to think about language conventions: `csquotes` can adapt to the current language).

---

Just because I mentioned it in the comments as well

```
\epigraph{ "Some quote."}{\textit{From me.}
```

is a syntax error. The final closing brace is missing. It should have been

```
\epigraph{ "Some quote."}{\textit{From me.}}
```